# Como manejar una relación muchos a muchos en laravel 6

Tags: laravel-6

Buen día, estoy haciendo una haciendo una relación muchos a muchos entre dos tablas en la cual, la tabla intermedia la nombre mensaje y no se como se manejaría en laravel pues e visto que la relación muchos a muchos simplemente mandan las llaves foráneas por ejemplo de usuarios y roles, crea una tabla intermedia de user_role en el cual solo recibe la id de usuarios y roles, pero en ese caso yo quiero que en mis mensajes se mande la id mi administrador y mi alumno en una tabla intermedia y que se maneje como mensajes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quisiera saber como puedo representarlo en mis modelos para poder mostrar esa información.

De ante mano gracias

Comment: Deberías manejar la tabla Mensaje como un modelo independiente y no como una tabla intermedia

Answer (score 2):

Para conseguir lo que quieres necesitas crear 3 tablas, las tablas administrador y alumno, y la tabla pivote mensaje que guarde el id del administrador y el id del alumno.

Tabla administrador

```
// create_administrador_table
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('administrador', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('nombre');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Tabla alumno

```
// create_alumno_table
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('alumno', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('semestre');
            $table->string('carrera');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Tabla Mensaje

```
 // create_mensajes_table
 public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('mensaje', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->integer('administrador_id')->unsigned();
                $table->foreign('administrador_id')->references('id')->on('administrador')->onDelete('cascade');
                $table->integer('alumno_id')->unsigned();
                $table->foreign('alumno_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
```

Una vez que tienes las tablas creadas, tienes que definir las relaciones entre ellas en sus modelos. La relacion entre los modelos es belongsToMany, indicamos las relaciones en el modelo Administrador y Alumno.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Administrador extends Model
{

    public function alumnos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Administrador::class, 'mensaje')->withPivot('mensaje')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Definimos las relaciones en ambos modelos.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Alumno extends Model
{
    public function administradores()
    {
            return $this->belongsToMany(Alumno::class, 'mensaje')->withPivot('mensaje')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

El segundo parámetro de la funcion belongsToMany indica el nombre de la tabla pivote, en este caso 'mensaje', y con la función withPivot('campo') indicamos los campos adicionales que tiene la tabla pivote. La función withTimeStamps() sirve para añadir las marcas de tiempo en la tabla pivote cada vez que se agrega un record.

Ahora solo queda crear diferentes alumnos y administrador, y crear los mensajes.

Para hacer que un administrador envie un mensaje:

```
$administrador = Administrador::find(1); // Buscamos un administrador

$administrador->alumnos()->attach('id_alumno', ['mensaje' => 'Hola esto es el mensaje a enviar al alumno con id_alumno']; // Hacemos un attach de los mensajes a los alumnos
```

El administrador con el id = 1, manda un mensaje al alumno o alumnos especificados en el campo id_alumno.